# Having "___ in (select distinct ___ from #temp)" in Case statement

Tags: t-sql, case

I'm trying to achieve this

```
select
   case
      when Org_CD = '1111' or Org_CD in (select distinct New_Org_CD from #temp) then 'International'
   end as 'Organisation',
count(*)
from #AnotherTempTable
group by
   case
      when Org_CD = '1111' or Org_CD in (select distinct New_Org_CD from #temp) then 'International'
   end
```

I received this error:

> Column '#AnotherTempTable.Org_Cd' is
>   invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Is it because I cannot use "in" keyword inside the case statements? If yes, any known workarounds would be more than helpful!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: All that is going to do is provide a single column, containing "Organisation" for every `org_cd` that is either exists in #temp or 1111.

Comment: I just updated it with a count(*). I was trying to get a count(*) for those Organisations that matches 1111 or the other Organisation codes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this...

```
select
    Org_CD, count(*)
from
    #AnotherTempTable A
    JOIN
    (select distinct New_Org_CD from #temp UNION SELECT '1111') T ON A.Org_CD = T.New_Org_CD
group by
   Org_CD
```

You can't have an inline IN like this (CASE + aggregate)

If this is not OK, please give sample data and output

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a variation of gbn's solution using 'Union'. Thanks all.